# Sasuser sample data sets? where are they?

Tags: sas

I'm a novice in SAS and wanted to access ALL the data sets under the sasuser library. However, I read somewhere that they don't come when installing SAS. I used this link to get some of them : http://support.sas.com/kb/11/268.html

Where can I get access to all of them ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: Are you referring to the question coming under pointer no.5 in off-topic questions ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MikeW This is pretty clearly on topic, as this is asking how to use a programming tool (SAS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in using these code to create the sample data sets:

http://support.sas.com/publishing/cert/sampdata.txt

Comment: Hey, I had looked up this link as well, but was looking for a better option. But it turns out that this itself was easy, just using this code as it is gives me everything that I need. Thanks a lot.